# Referring to Realm.io FK objects by ID

Tags: android, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.android, realm

I'm trying to create a Realm database in Android that mirrors one I have in SQL Server. The idea is to update periodically the one on Android so that both have the same data.

To keep it simple, let's assume I have three tables: Object, Color, Shape. My main table Object has this form:

```
ID      |  int
------------------
Name    |  string
------------------
IDColor |  int
------------------
IDShape |  int
```

where IDColor and IDShape refer to the Color and Shape tables. The content of these two is unimportant.

What I would like to do is to define something like this on Android:

```
public class MyObject extends RealmObject {
    @Required
    private String name;
    private Color color;
    private Shape shape;
}
```

This way I can refer to MyObject.color and MyObject.shape directly. However, this way AFAIK I can't specify color and shape by their ID's, so realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate won't work.

Is there an alternative that allows me to import my JSON directly (ideal) or after some pre- or post-processing?

Thanks

**EDIT: I have found a way to do something akin to this using Xamarin.** See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm is an object database so importing the 3 tables independently doesn't really work in that case. You would need to do some pre-processing that setup the object structure.

You could do it by converting your input-data to JSONObject and use the `realm.createOrUpdateFromJsonObject()` method. That behaves similar to `copyToRealmOrUpdate` except it works directly on JSON.

Pseudocode:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myObjectJson);
obj.put("color", getColorJson(obj.getInt("IDColor")));
realm.creteOrUpdateFromJSonObject(obj);
```

Comment: (Actually, I meant to say createOrUpdateFromJSonObject.) I was hoping to avoid this pre-processing but it will have to do. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, pre-processing is necessary, but on the upside you don't have to create all the relationships when you query the data afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I no longer use "vanilla Android", but I found that one can do what I intended with my original question in Xamarin, as follows:

```
public class MyObject: RealmObject
{
    public int IdColor {get; set;}
    public Color color
    {
        get
        {
            return realm.All<Color>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == IdColor);
        }
        set
        {
            IdColor = value.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Any custom getters and setters are ignored by Realm, so the objects are not persisted in the database. This is the easiest way I found to replicate the FK behaviour of traditional SQL databases in Realm.